# Usage of extern variable in c files

Tags: c, extern

I am trying to build a simple test case for extern variables using 4 files.
The files are as follows

//header.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func1();
void func2();
extern int var;
```

//main.c

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    func2();
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

//func1.c

```
#include "header.h"

void func1()
{
printf("I am in function 1\t var = %d", var);
return ;
}
```

//func2.c

```
#include "header.h"

void func2()
{
int var = 4;
     printf("I am function 2\n");
     return ;
}
```

I am trying to understand the concept of an extern variable. I compiled these files as

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c func1.c
gcc -c func2.c
```

and linked them together as

```
gcc -o main main.o func1.o func2.o
```

I got an error saying

```
func1.o: In function `func1':
func1.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `var'
```

Why is that? I defined it in func2 and then use it in another file. What is wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are declaring a variable inside the function, it is a local variable. 
It scope will be with in that function block. When you are using the `extern` key word it search for variable in the global section.  So you have to declare the variable as a global variable.

```
#include "header.h"
int var = 4;
void func2()
{
   printf("I am function 2\n");
   return ;
}
```

Output will be ,

```
 I am function 2
 I am in function 1  var = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

`int var = 4;` <-- you have to move this out of `func2()`.

As it stands (you declared it inside `func2()`, it's only visible within that function.

To make it visible on other compilation unit (via `extern`), you need to move it out to its file scope.